# Apache Phoenix: Why is adding a column to a table slower than adding a column to a view?

Tags: apache, hbase, apache-phoenix

Why is adding a column to a table much slower than adding it to a view, considering that Phoenix/Hbase does not store empty cells?

In the code below, it takes around 6 secs to add a column to a table, and 36 ms to do it to a view. Why is that?

> 0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase> create table mytable(id bigint not null primary key);
>
> No rows affected (1.339 seconds)
>
> 0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase> create view myview as select * from mytable;
>
> No rows affected (0.047 seconds)
>
> 0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase> alter table mytable add mycol1 varchar;
>
> No rows affected (5.965 seconds)
>
> 0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase> alter view myview add mycol2 varchar;
>
> No rows affected (0.036 seconds)

Comment: did you repeatedly run the alters to get a baseline within the shell?  is it stable?  If stable, it could be due the way Phoenix represents a view and the way hbase adds a column to a table, maybe it had to touch all rows?  all hypothetical

Comment: I have repeatedly gotten these results, yes. Alter table and alter view running time converge when you have many columns (>2 dozens). Regarding the underlying architecture of hbase/phoenix, as I understand hbase doesn't store empty columns (only column families). A view vs a table in terms of phoenix - as I understand - is basically the same thing. They are both virtual tables anyway.